# images not loading when shifted to localhost

Tags: html, image, localhost

Been working on a watch customizer. Initially worked outside localhost (worked perfectly)

**Not on localhost**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpRgl.jpg

**On localhost**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieiRA.jpg

Sorry for posting the images in an external website.

If you would have noticed the thumnails are loading perfectly in when hosted on the localhost, but the same image is not being loaded in the customizer.

The snippet of html is as follows

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">      
    <div id="content">
        <div id="fpd">
            <div class="fpd-product" title="Face Black" data-
thumbnail="images/faces/Black.png">
            <img src="images/faces/Black.png" title="Black" data-    parameters='{"x": 198, "y": 154, "colors": "test", "price": 20}' />
        </div>
            <div class="fpd-product" title="Face Black Shiny" data-   thumbnail="images/faces/Black Shiny.png">
            <img src="images/faces/Black Shiny.png" title="Black Shiny"   data-parameters='{"x": 198, "y": 154, "colors": "test", "price": 20}' />
         </div>
             </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just check the img path if you are not on localhost and compare it to the working one, you will find your error there.

Comment: @Sebsemillia i do not think the image path matters because the thumbnail and the image required for the customizer have the same path. The thumbnail loads correctly but the customizer shows only blank images.